# after updating, my laptop doesn't turn on

Tags: boot, 15.10

I'm using Ubuntu 15.10. firstly i updated my laptop as usual, it gives me instruction of restart, after restart my laptop not on.
I tried 'Advanced Options for Ubuntu' recovery process, but nothing works.

Here's the error message:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to run fsck manualy.  boot with a dvd or pendrive and got to a terminal.

Then type  `fdisk -l` you should get an output like

```
Device       Start       End   Sectors   Size Type
/dev/sda1     2048   1050623   1048576   512M EFI System
/dev/sda2  1050624   1550335    499712   244M Linux filesystem
/dev/sda3  1550336 468860927 467310592 222,9G Linux LVM
```

whith "/dev/sda*" or "/dev/sdb*" or something like

```
Disk /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root: 213 GiB, 228665065472 bytes, 446611456 sectors
```

if you use lvm partitions
Then you can run fsck with

```
  fsck /dev/sda1
```

or

```
fsck /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root
```

Comment: thanks sir.
i have another question: can i install Ubuntu_16.04 or any other flavor of Linux without data loss.

Comment: Yes. Just don't format the partitions you can install over the current one. But since your filesystem is in a inconsistent state you may have problems.
I suggest you try the fsck solution first. You can start a shell with the dvd